# display data in next row when the next id comes

Tags: php

I have a table in database like this:

ID, features, Values : ID will be 1, 2, 3.... 
features will be color, size, material.... 
values will be red, 13inch, silicon...

I stored it like this:

ID 
1
1
1

Features
color
 size
material

values
red
13in
silicon

and it continues for product 2... . I am trying to display it in tabular form which i am not getting.

Actually it has to go to next row when id -2 comes... but it keeps on displaying in the same row....

can somebody tell me how to do it?

I tried like this

```
echo "<table width='100%'>";
echo "<tr><th>color</th>
<th>size</th>
<th>material</th></tr>";
echo "<tr>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    echo "<td>".$row['values']."</td>";


} 
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

EDITED ********

This is my complete code

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))

{
$id = $_POST['id'];

$test = "SELECT id, features, values FROM mytable WHERE features IN ('color', 'size', 'material') AND id IN (" . implode(',',$id) .")";
$result = mysql_query($test) or die (mysql_error());
echo "<table width='100%'>";
echo "<tr><th>color</th>
<th>size</th>
<th>material</th></tr>";
echo "<tr>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    echo "<td>".$row['values']."</td>";


} 
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
}
```

and the output for `print_r(mysql_fetch_assoc($result));`

`Array ([id] => 1 [features] => color [values] => red )`

Comment: I strongly encourage you to normalize your tables if they aren't. Could you add the code you've tried, to the question

Comment: Please add your exact table structure and your mysql query to the question. Then try to following before the while loop and add the exact output to your question please: `print_r(mysql_fetch_assoc($result));`

Comment: you're looping by `<td>` only, how it should create your `<tr>`?

Comment: But if i close `</tr>` inside the loop. everything comes in new row.

Comment: @ DanFromGermany: i have edited my code above. Can you please check where i am wrong

Comment: @user2823107 sorry, I didn't get it. New rows should go to the new row, right? that's what a normal table looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should solve the problem:

```
$table_markup = '<tr>';
$current_row = null;

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {

    if ( $current_row === null ) {
        $current_row = $row['id'];
    }

    if ( $current_row != $row['id'] ) {
        $current_row = $row['id'];
        $table_markup .= '</tr><tr>';
    }

    $table_markup .=  '<td>' . $row['values'] . '</td>';
}

/* cutting off the last opened-TR tage */
$table_markup .= substr($table_markup, 0, -4);

echo $table_markup;
```

Comment: I want to display only the data in `values` column. And that should break when the next id appears in ID column

Comment: i am not allowed to post image here or else i would have posted the database structure. I know am not able to explain it properly so only am not getting the answer for it. Sorry

Comment: @user2823107 no worries. you can upload the image somewhere else and post the link in the original post, of course if you think that might help :)

Comment: @ Mahdi: can you please help me

Comment: @user2823107 aha, I see what you mean now. can you change the table structure or not?

Comment: @user2823107 take a look at my updated answer, i hope that helps

Comment: @ Mahdi: its exaactly what i wanted... thank you very much for your precious time... thanks a ton. But it displays every record twice

Comment: I got it! Thanks once again Mahdi